# VPN Connection Failed in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, vpn

Somehow after system updates last night I'm unable to connect to VPN (Cisco open-vpn).

I traced `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog`

```
Dec 15 12:25:18 aftab-ThinkPad-Edge-E431 NetworkManager[1104]: <info> Starting VPN service 'vpnc'...
Dec 15 12:25:18 aftab-ThinkPad-Edge-E431 NetworkManager[1104]: <info> VPN service 'vpnc' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc), PID 5025
Dec 15 12:25:18 aftab-ThinkPad-Edge-E431 NetworkManager[1104]: <info> VPN service 'vpnc' appeared; activating connections
Dec 15 12:25:18 aftab-ThinkPad-Edge-E431 NetworkManager[1104]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
Dec 15 12:25:18 aftab-ThinkPad-Edge-E431 NetworkManager[1104]: <info> VPN connection 'Vonage VPN' (Connect) reply received.
Dec 15 12:25:18 aftab-ThinkPad-Edge-E431 NetworkManager[1104]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun1, iface: tun1)
Dec 15 12:25:18 aftab-ThinkPad-Edge-E431 NetworkManager[1104]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun1, iface: tun1): no ifupdown configuration found.
Dec 15 12:25:18 aftab-ThinkPad-Edge-E431 NetworkManager[1104]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun1: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Dec 15 12:25:19 aftab-ThinkPad-Edge-E431 NetworkManager[1104]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun1, iface: tun1)
Dec 15 12:25:19 aftab-ThinkPad-Edge-E431 NetworkManager[1104]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Dec 15 12:25:19 aftab-ThinkPad-Edge-E431 NetworkManager[1104]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
Dec 15 12:25:19 aftab-ThinkPad-Edge-E431 NetworkManager[1104]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Dec 15 12:25:19 aftab-ThinkPad-Edge-E431 NetworkManager[1104]: <info> Policy set 'Noduco2' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Dec 15 12:25:19 aftab-ThinkPad-Edge-E431 NetworkManager[1104]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Dec 15 12:25:23 aftab-ThinkPad-Edge-E431 wpa_supplicant[1192]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Dec 15 12:25:24 aftab-ThinkPad-Edge-E431 NetworkManager[1104]: <info> VPN service 'vpnc' disappeared
Dec 15 12:25:24 aftab-ThinkPad-Edge-E431 wpa_supplicant[1192]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
Dec 15 12:27:23 aftab-ThinkPad-Edge-E431 wpa_supplicant[1192]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Dec 15 12:27:24 aftab-ThinkPad-Edge-E431 wpa_supplicant[1192]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
```

What can be the possible reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Your core issue is here:

```
SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun1, iface: tun1)
SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun1, iface: tun1): no ifupdown configuration found.
```

**When the VPN service is started, it adds a network interface `tun1`, and tries to configure it. However, there is no configuration for `tun1` in `/etc/network/interfaces`, so the VPN service stops right there.**

Now, I don't know enough about VPNs on Linux to tell you exactly what to do. Maybe it was `tun0` before, and another `tun0` has been added to the machine, so it increased by one? Maybe you can just set-up `tun1` in `/etc/network/interfaces`?